# adding ads to Visual Studio sln for Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2013, ads

I have made a game in Unity and would like to add ads to the app for Windows Phone 8. I followed the instructions on this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-8-adcontrol-walkthrough-api%28v=msads.20%29.aspx

The part that doesnt work are these two lines of code.

```
Grid grid = (Grid)this.LayoutRoot.Children[1];
grid.Children.Add(adControl);
```

I dont have a grid on my mainpage.xaml and am not sure the correct way to implement it. If anyone can help show what my mainpage should look like, I would love the help! This is what it shows currently:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="MagicTapBall.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Orientation="Portrait" SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" BackKeyPress="PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress" OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded">

</DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```

Comment: Why don't you add a grid to hold what you need and the drawing surface?

Comment: That what I would like to do, but Im not sure exactly to to go about it. the code looks like it ads the "ad system" to the child of the grid. Do you have an example of how to make a grid system?